# Select object property with same name, but capitalized

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm parsing some data, but for some reason the object's property name is sometimes capitalized. For example, sometimes the property name is `content-type`, whereas at other times it is `Content-Type`.

This is how I am selecting the property...

`const ct = payload.responseHeaders['content-type'] || payload.responseHeaders['Content-Type']`

But is there a shorter syntax or, more specifically, a way to ignore the letter case when selecting?

Comment: Not really. If you need to do this for multiple properties, transform the object into lower-cased keys first

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok damn

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing is probably to find a match in `Object.keys()` via a regex:

```
const headerKey = Object.keys(payload.responseHeaders).find(k => /content-type/i.test(k))
const header = payload.responseHeaders[headerKey]
```

Comment: i imagine its a lot less efficient, but it does technically answer my question, so ill vote it up :)